# How to loop within a loop in django while passing multiple context

Tags: python, django, django-views

I having trouble trying to access the foreign key element from my template. I am trying to pass multiple contexts using class view like this:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = "homepage/home.html"
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author_links'] = Author_link.objects.all()
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['extra_links'] = Extra_link.objects.all()
        context['poems'] = Poem.objects.all()
        return context
```

my models.py file:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Author_link(models.Model):
    url_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.url_text

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Extra_link(models.Model):
    url_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.url_text
```

however when I am trying to loop through the context I can't seem to access the foreign key of each item:

```
{% for author in object_list %}
  <li class = "collection-item">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">{{author.name}}</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          {% for item in author.item_set.all %}
            <p>{{item.url}}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

what I am trying to do is loop through the authors and at the same time under each author loop through the urls that are associated with each author.

Comment: There's no relationship in your models between Author and Category. And what is `item_set` supposed to be? Exactly what are you trying to iterate over for each author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you have

```
{% for item in author.item_set.all %}
    <p>{{item.url}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

you should have something like

```
{% for item in author.author_link_set.all %}
    <p>{{item.url}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This manager (`author.author_link_set`) is added to each author because there is a foreign key from `Author_link` to `Author`.

side note: the convention for class names in python is Pascal Case, e.g., `AuthorLink` not `Author_link`. I mention this because I'm not 100% sure if I have correctly guessed the name of the reverse relation on author (it might be `author.authorlink_set`, I've never seen an underscore in a model name - django may do something special in that case)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. There was a small mistake that I made while copying the code to this site. I changed it to what I was actually doing.

Comment: @SubhadeepSarkar you could write `{% if author.author_link_set.all %}class="collapsible-body"{% endif %}` if you have a lot of authors you can avoid running lots of queries by using `queryset = Author.objects.all().prefetch_related("author_link_set")`